# Doing away with one struct definition in case two structs have inherently same structure

Tags: c

I have two physical entities which have same structure. What is the ideal way to handle this scenario.

For example:

```
struct graphlet_vector {
    int a;
    int* data;
}

struct group_vector {
    int a;
    int *data;
}
```

group vectors are defined as aggregated graphlet vectors over a range hence the structure is bound to remain same over the period of time. Hence having two structure for the same thing seems redundant.

I cannot use something like this:
`typedef struct graphlet_vec struct group_vec`(although the following works fine: `typedef struct graphlet_vec group_vec`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it imperative to keep the struct keyword? I don't see any problem otherwise

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi just a convention I was following everywhere. Was interested to know if there is some other way to enforce it.

Comment: If the two things are conceptually or semantically different, keep them separate, and don't worry about "redundancy". If you have two composite types you need to represent, then represent them as two different types. The fact they have the same internal representation isn't really germane to this decision. Your question suggests you want to continue to *use* two distinct names, so saving the trouble of typing two small `struct` definitions in a header is miniscule. The `struct` definitions will disappear after compilation anyway, so you're not conserving any actual resources.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Could you elaborate on why/how `struct` definition would disappear after compilation?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam because machine code doesn't have `struct`s, just instructions and bytes of data. The `struct` definitions just tell the compiler how to represent the data, once that representation has been made concrete in a compiled executable the definition has served its purpose and is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want them to be the same type, you can use two typedefs:

```
struct g_vector { /* ... */ };
typedef struct g_vector graph_vector;
typedef struct g_vector group_vector;
```

If you prefer to refer to the types as `struct graph_vector` and `struct group_vector` rather than just by a single identifier for each, there's no really clean way to do it (`struct foo` and `struct bar` are always distinct types) -- but you *could* use the preprocessor:

```
struct g_vector { /* ... */ };
#define graph_vector g_vector
#define group_vector g_vector
```

On the other hand, you should consider whether you really want them to be the same type. They have different names, so they obviously have different meanings to you; otherwise you would have defined a single type. Is there going to be code that can operate on an object of either type? If not, keep them distinct.

If you want to treat them as distinct types in some cases, but as the same type in others, that's a bit trickier. You can either define them as the same type and be careful that you don't mix up the operations in cases where you want them to be distinct (you lose some compile-time type checking that way). Or you can define them as distinct types and implement the common functions using `void*`. (Or you can switch from C to C++ and derive them from a common parent type using class inheritance.)